# PythonのNumPyの値が重複しているときの平均値を求めたい

Tags: python, numpy

現在、Pythonで重複する値の平均を出そうとしています。
具体的には、

```
x = np.array([0, 0, 1, 1, 1])
y = np.array([0, 0, 1, 0, 0])
z = np.array([2, 3, 4, 3, 6])
```

という配列から、

```
new_x = np.array([0, 1, 1])
new_y = np.array([0, 1, 0])
new_z = np.array([2.5, 5., 3.])
```

もしくは

```
new_x = np.array([0, 0, 1, 1, 1])
new_y = np.array([0, 0, 1, 0, 0])
new_z = np.array([2.5, 2.5, 5., 3., 5.])
```

という値が欲しいです。
`x`と`y`はインデックスの値、`z[i]`は(`x[i]`, `y[i]`)のときの値で
`x[0] == x[1], y[0] == y[1]`なので、`new_z`の要素に`z[0]`と`z[1]`の平均を入るという処理がしたいです。
なにかいい案はないでしょうか？

Comment: この例だと `x`, `y`, `z` の長さは 5 ですが、実際に処理するデータだとどのくらいの長さになりますか？

Comment: 実際だと700から800くらいあります。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`np.ravel_multi_index()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ravel_multi_index.html)（あるいは[`np.unique()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html)等でも可能）を用いて、（x, y）の二次元座標を一次元座標に変換した後、[`np.bincount()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.bincount.html)を用いて各座標の合計と総数を計算します。

例：

```py
def pos_means1(x, y, z):
    xy = np.ravel_multi_index([x, y], (x.max()+1, y.max()+1))
    means = np.bincount(xy, z) / np.bincount(xy)
    return means[xy]


def pos_means2(x, y, z):
    unq, xy, cnt = np.unique([x, y], axis=1,
                             return_inverse=True, return_counts=True)
    means = np.bincount(xy, z) / cnt
    return unq[0], unq[1], means
```

動作：

```
In [4]: x = np.array([0, 0, 1, 1, 1])
   ...: y = np.array([0, 0, 1, 0, 1])
   ...: z = np.array([2, 3, 4, 3, 6])

In [5]: pos_means1(x, y, z)
Out[5]: array([2.5, 2.5, 5. , 3. , 5. ])

In [6]: pos_means2(x, y, z)
Out[6]: (array([0, 1, 1]),
         array([0, 0, 1]),
         array([2.5, 3. , 5. ]))
```

Answer (score 1):

NumPyを使った方法ではありませんが、いかがでしょうか。700～800個程度のデータでしたらパフォーマンス的には問題ないかと思います。

```py
x = [0, 0, 1, 1, 1]
y = [0, 0, 1, 0, 1]
z = [2, 3, 4, 3, 6]

from collections import defaultdict, Counter
z_total = defaultdict(lambda: 0)
z_count = Counter()

for xi, yi, zi in zip(x, y, z):
    z_total[(xi, yi)] += zi
    z_count[(xi, yi)] += 1

indexes = set((xi, yi) for xi, yi in zip(x, y))
z_average = {k: z_total[k] / z_count[k] for k in indexes}

new_x = [0, 0, 1, 1, 1]
new_y = [0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
new_z = [z_average[k] for k in zip(new_x, new_y)]

new_z
# [2.5, 2.5, 5.0, 3.0, 3.0]
```

Answer (score 0):

シンプルに。。。

```
x = [0, 0, 1, 1, 1]
y = [0, 0, 1, 0, 1]
z = [2, 3, 4, 3, 6]

lst = [[(xi, yi), zi] for xi, yi, zi in zip(x, y, z)]
dic = {k:sum(map(lambda x:x[1] if x[0]==k else 0, lst))/
         sum(map(lambda x:x[0]==k, lst)) for k, v in lst}

new_x = [0, 0, 1, 1, 1]
new_y = [0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
new_z = [dic[k] for k in zip(new_x, new_y)]
print(new_z)  # [2.5, 2.5, 5.0, 3.0, 3.0]
```

numpy の array も同じパターンで

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([0, 0, 1, 1, 1])
y = np.array([0, 0, 1, 0, 1])
z = np.array([2, 3, 4, 3, 6])

lst = [[(xi, yi), zi] for xi, yi, zi in zip(x, y, z)]
dic = {k:sum(map(lambda x:x[1] if x[0]==k else 0, lst))/
         sum(map(lambda x:x[0]==k, lst)) for k, v in lst}

new_x = np.array([0, 0, 1, 1, 1])
new_y = np.array([0, 0, 1, 0, 0])
new_z = np.array([dic[k] for k in zip(new_x, new_y)])
print(new_z) # [2.5 2.5 5.  3.  3. ]
```